# SAS Files in Databricks

Tags: azure, csv, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to convert SAS files to CSV in Azure Databricks. SAS files are in Azure Blob. I am successfully able to mount the azure bolb in Databricks, but when I read from it, it has no files even though there are files on Blob. Has anyone done this before?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please add the commands which you have tried along with the error message received?

Comment: I have used the following code to mount the azure blob:

`dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
  mount_point = "/mnt/<mount-name>",
  extra_configs = {"<conf-key>":dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "<scope-name>", key = "<key-name>")})`
 This throws no errors.

Comment: Then I check the contents with `%fs ls` 
This lists the mount storage location.
 I check that with `display(dbutils.fs.ls("dbfs:/mnt/"))`
and then with my mount name `display(dbutils.fs.ls("dbfs:/mnt/harsh"))` which gives an error of `java.io.FileNotFoundException: / is not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have mounted a Blob storage container correctly.

Here is the complete steps to mount a blob storage container and access the files:

[image]

Reference: [Mount an Azure Blob Storage Container](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, turns out there was a typo and so it didn't work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was an error in the first step while mounting the Blob storage. Thank you for all the help, really appreciate it!